# How to get amount in Razorpay integration

Tags: android, webhooks, razorpay

I am integrating Razorpay in Android. I want amount detail that I paid through Razorpay in response  when the payment got success.

I have implement PaymentResultListener() in my payment activity but it return only razorpay_payment_id, then I implement PaymentResultWithDataListener() it return me **razorpay_payment_id** and **PaymentData** in PaymentData I receive below JSON:

```
{
    "D$_X_": {
        "nameValuePairs": {
            "razorpay_payment_id": "pay_Aqs0wR5jn6mHVa"
        }
    },
    "Q_$2$": "sample@email.com",
    "R$$r_": "pay_Aqs0wR5jn6mHVa",
    "a_$P$": "+918976543210"
}
```

I want to log my payment details so that i can store it on my DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your amount in notes. And when razorpay send webhook there will be amount in notes. You can retrieve this and store in your db.